# Find the Möbius transformation $w = L(z)$ mapping the unit disk $|z| < 1$ onto itself

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I have been trying the following problem:

Find the Möbius transformation $w = L(z)$ mapping the
unit disk $|z| < 1$ onto itself in such a way that $w(\alpha)=\alpha$ and  $arg\; w'(\alpha)=\theta$ with $|\alpha|<1$

but have not been able to solve it. I know the equation $$f(z)=e^{i \theta}\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z} \ \ |a|<1 \ \ 0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi.$$
maps the unit circle on the unit circle but I don't see very clear how to use the second condition $w '(\alpha) = \theta$. Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach it to find a “conjugate” map which is simpler to investigate. Here we can conjugate $L$ with
$$
 T(z) = \frac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}
$$
so that the fixed point is transformed to the origin.

If $L$ is a Möbius transformation mapping the unit disk onto itself with $L(\alpha) = \alpha$ then
$$
 S = T \circ L \circ T^{-1}
$$
is a Möbius transformation mapping the unit disk onto itself with $S(0) = 0$ and $S'(0) = L'(\alpha)$.

It follows that $S(z) = e^{i\theta} z$, and therefore
$$
 L(z) = T^{-1}(e^{i\theta} T(z)) \, .
$$